# Rails 3.1 Not Reloading Changed Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sinatra, ruby-1.9.2

I'm seeing a bug/feature in my Ruby 1.9.2 applications.  Any changes to **views** (not ruby files) require a server restart.  I initially encountered this in a Rails app, but I've tested the same thing in a minimal Sinatra app too.

I'll include a simple app to demonstrate

```
# testapp.rb
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  [0,1,2].to_s  #change this to [0,1].to_s
end
```

This is my procedure:

- `ruby testapp.rb` (runs thin server for me)
- load the page
- open the file and edit the view
- reload the page (I see no changes)
- kill the server
- restart the server (changes now visible)

I've been developing in Ruby 1.8.7 on Rails 3 for the last several months.  Having to restart the server on any view change slows down development severely.

I've ready [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027327/rails-development-environment-not-reloading-views-on-change), but in my version of Rails (3.1.0 rc4), the config variable is already set as per that answer.  Additionally I can replicate the error using Sinatra, so that doesn't seem like it's the case.

Can anyone shed light on this issue?

Ruby version: ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-linux]
Server: thin 1.2.11 (also tested this with Sinatra/Webrick)

**EDIT 7/13, Clarification**
The Sinatra thing is a separate issue--Sinatra's source reloading is disabled by default.  I used this code to test out the behavior:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/reloader'
require 'haml'

set :views, 'views'

get '/' do
end

get '/test' do
  haml :test
end
```

With this, I made a file: `views/test.haml`.  Modifying it while the server is running **does** show a change when the page is reloaded.  Thanks to Tiredpixel for pointing this out

**Unresolved Issue**: why does Rails 3.1 on Ruby 1.9.2 not reload the **views**?  I'm able to get ruby files to load, but not haml and erb files.  I end up restarting the server just to see if a bug was actually fixed (or not fixed) because of a file not loading properly.

**EDIT/SOLUTION (copied from my comment in the accepted answer)**:

The problem was in `config/environments/development.rb`

```
config.cache_classes = false
```

Even after we checked this was correct, we still had the issue.  Further down in the file we had:

```
config.threadsafe!
```

What this does is set the following 3 flags to true: `config.allow_concurrency`, `config.preload_frameworks`, and (surprise!) `config.cache_classes`.

To fix: move `config.threadsafe!` above `config.cache_classes`, so that it doesn't get implicitly overridden.

Comment: I just created a fresh 3.1.0 rc4 app and [pushed it to github](https://github.com/ezkl/reload_test). It has a controller with a single method and a route. I'm running 1.9.2-p180. When I run `thin start`, browse `http://localhost:3000/`, make changes to `app/views/pages/index.html.erb`, views reload properly.

Comment: Thanks for pushing this.  Apparently it was an issue with `config.threadsafe!` writing over `config.cache_classes`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rails is normally configured to automatically reload on every request, whilst in the development environment. This doesn't happen for files in `lib/`, though.

The experience you describe with Sinatra is intended (automatic reloading was removed in 0.9.2): http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#reloading; the [Shotgun](http://rubygems.org/gems/shotgun) gem can be installed to perform this reloading.

Comment: Hm, I guess my post was pointing at 2 different issues and I didn't realize it.  I'll update it

Comment: Have you checked `config/environments/development.rb`

    `config.cache_classes = false`

and

    `config.action_controller.perform_caching = false`

?

Comment: So this was going down the right path.  Someone on my team got it.  We already had `config.cache_classes = false` (as well as the other flag you mentioned).  However, further down in the file we had: `config.threadsafe!`.  What this does is set the following 3 flags to true: `config.allow_concurrency`, `config.preload_frameworks`, `config.cache_classes`.  The fix, then, was to move `config.threadsafe!` to above `config.cache_classes`, so that it doesn't get implicitly overridden.

Comment: Excellent - I didn't know `config.threadsafe!` did that - thanks for the explanation!